# Calculating image entropy

Tags: image, grayscale, entropy

I am looking for a code that could be used to calculate information entropy of the image that is attached in this message ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahdk6.jpg ). I googled potential answers to this question and found some description of how to do this (e.g. http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html). However, this did not work for me and the image in question. I would really appreciate anyone's help because I am not that skilled in Matlab.

Thanks and best wishes,

Dario

Comment: Howcome it didn't work? Anyway, for what purpose you'd want to calculate the entropy? I think it is a quite poor measure of randomness as it doesn't take spatial correlations into account, on 1-bit images (just B&W) I'd rather divide it into for example `4 x 4` or `8 x 8` pixel regions and calculate entropy on these instead of single pixels. Alternatively I would also look in to the distribution of FFT coefficients as "random" images have coefficients on all frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it pretty simply in the Terminal at the command-line with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

So, you run:

```
convert image.jpg -print '%[entropy]\n' null:
0.302578
```